# Does changing my name (not my username) can have any side effect for existing GitHub repos?

Tags: git, github

I would like to change my name on my GitHub profile and I was wondering if the change can have any side effects on existing repositories. I mean the first and last name, not my username. I've noticed that commit messages use the username, not the name itself, so I suppose everything should be fine.

Also, my name is of Hungarian origin and it contains a special character, the "á" character. I can just use "a" in worst case but "á" and "a" are two different sounds, so it would be better for me to use the correct one "á". Will that be a problem for GitHub? As far as I know UTF-8 is well supported these days and shouldn't cause any issue.

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to your **display name**, not your **username**?

Comment: Yes, the name that shows up the largest when you open the profile, above the username.

Comment: Note the name shown on GitHub is only used for commits you make through the web UI (and presumably GitHub Desktop) anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I only use the terminal. Do you know anything abou the UTF-8 handling?

Comment: There should be no problem with UTF-8 on the user name.

Comment: @KarthikNayak I meant the display name, not the user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places you can change your name when using GitHub.

The first is the local setting `user.name`, which provides your personal name to Git.  This value is baked into every commit you make.  It supports the full range of UTF-8 and you should be fine setting it to whatever value.

The other is in the GitHub user interface, and this is used to show who you are in notifications and elsewhere in the interface.  This also should support UTF-8 just fine, even though the username does not.

I have a colleague with the character “í” in his name (and another with “ß”) and both work fine.  I've also seen people use Cyrillic characters, Chinese, and Japanese.  As a consequence, you should be good to go in both places.